# How can I find the convolution of these two functions?

Tags: integration, convolution

*Restrucutred this question, as it felt more natural to be asked in a different matter than I first wrote.*

Given the functions

$$f(t) = \frac{e^{-2|t|}}{4},\quad g(t) = \frac{e^{-3|t|}}{6}$$

Find the convolution $f(t) * g(t)$

$$f(t)*g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-\tau)g(\tau)\,d\tau =\frac{1}{24} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|t-\tau|}e^{-3|\tau|}\,d\tau$$

Because $t$ is a variable, how do I deal with this? It seems like I can't just divide it into two integrands, because $|\tau|$ won't always have the same discontinuity point as $|t-\tau|$. In fact, this only happens when $t=0$.

---

Assuming $t<0\,:$

$$\frac{1}{24} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|t-\tau|}e^{-3|\tau|}\,d\tau = \frac{1}{24}\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-2|t-\tau|}e^{3\tau}\,d\tau + \int_{0}^\infty e^{2(t-\tau)}e^{-3\tau}\,d\tau\right)$$

I don't know how to apply the sign replacement in the case of $e^{-2|t-\tau|}$ when integrating $(-\infty,0]$ due to the fact that if $|\tau| \ge |t|$, then we'd have a positive sign replace the absolute value function; but if $|\tau| < |t|$, a negative sign would replace the absolute value function.

Comment: I would consider the cases $t<0$, $t=0$ and $t>0$. Then you can split the integral with $t$ dependency.

Comment: @sonystarmap Ooh wait, don't bother replying. I will try using $t$ dependancy as you said. I didn't realize what you meant by that at first.

Comment: Why don't you just take Fourier transforms of f and g and find the inverse of Fourier transform of their products instead?
A very rough calculation gave me $\frac{1}{36(1+p^2\pi^2)^2}$ Find its inverse using mathematica or on wolfram alpha.

Comment: @SilverSlash From start I had the function $\frac{1}{(\omega^2+4)(\omega^2+9)}$. To find the inverse fourier transform of this function, I wanted to use the convolution theorem on $f(t)$, and $g(t)$ which are the inverse fourier transform of the two functions that make up the initial function.

Comment: @B.Lee , I didn't go through the calculation, but I would split the integral at $t$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty = \int_{-\infty}^t + \int_t^\infty$.

Comment: @sonystarmap Actually, I think I will have to split it up into four integrals. As the second exponential has its discontinuity point at $\tau = 0$. $\int^\infty_{-\infty} = \int_{-\infty}^{-|t|}+\int_{-|t|}^0 + \int_0^{|t|} + \int_{|t|}^\infty$

Comment: Do you have to use the definition of convolution, or are you allowed to use Fourier transforms?